# Overcoming multiplication of matrices with differing dimensions in Matlab integral

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, matlab-figure

I am having trouble with the following `integral2` operation on Matlab.

```
phi = @(x)(x>0).*exp(-1./x.^2);
R = @(xx,zz)phi(xx).*phi(1-xx).*phi(zz).*phi(1-zz);
omega = linspace(0,5,1000000);
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,1000000);
D = exp((10*1i*omega)./(40*pi)).*integral2(@(xx,zz)R(xx,zz).*exp(20.*omega.*1i.*((sin(theta)).*xx+(cos(theta)).*zz)),0,5,0,5);
```

The error message I get is that "the matrix dimensions must agree".

```
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in @(xx,zz)R(xx,zz).*exp(20.*omega.*1i.*((sin(theta)).*xx+(cos(theta)).*zz))

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 228)
        Z = FUN(X,Y);  NFE = NFE + 1;
Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 55)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);
Error in integral2Calc (line 9)
    [q,errbnd] = integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);
Error in integral2 (line 106)
    Q = integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);
```

I am unsure how to overcome this however. When I do `numel` on `xx`, `theta`, `omega` and `zz`, I find that they all have 1000000 elements.

I know this might be a "newbie" question, but I tried many things to get to this point without avail.

The equation I am trying to solve is:

[image]

Comment: Could you write down what equation you want to solve, or take a picture of the equation and upload it?

Comment: @qbzenker Sure, I added that with the edit.

Comment: What do you mean by solving? Do you want to calculate the integral for all the values of the parameters `theta` and `omega`?

Comment: @AVK Yes, exactly; because ultimately I want to plot it with imagesc by first converting to Cartesian coordinates via: 
`[omegaN,thetaN] = meshgrid(omega,theta);
xN = omegaN.*cos(thetaN);
yN = omegaN.*sin(thetaN);`

Comment: Taking the definition of `s` and `phi` into account, can't we limit both integrals to [0 1]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `integral2` can only calculate one integral at once. If you need
to calculate many integrals, you should use cycles (I have slightly reduced the grid size):

```
phi = @(x)(x>0).*exp(-1./x.^2);
R = @(xx,zz)phi(xx).*phi(1-xx).*phi(zz).*phi(1-zz);
    % generate the grid
[omega,theta]= meshgrid(linspace(0,5,200),linspace(0,2*pi,200));
D= zeros(size(omega)); % preallocate the memory
for ii= 1:size(omega,1)
    for jj= 1:size(omega,2)
        f= @(xx,zz)R(xx,zz).*exp(20.*omega(ii,jj).*1i.*...
            ((sin(theta(ii,jj))).*xx+(cos(theta(ii,jj))).*zz));
        D(ii,jj)= exp((10*1i*omega(ii,jj))./(40*pi)).*integral2(f,0,5,0,5);
    end
end
    % convert to Cartesian coordinates
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta,omega);
    % draw the results
figure;
surface(x,y,abs(D))
shading interp; axis square; view(3)
figure;
surface(x,y,real(D))
shading interp; axis square; view(3)
figure;
surface(x,y,imag(D))
shading interp; axis square; view(3)
```

The sizes of `xx` and `zz` in the integrand `R(xx,zz)` are not necesserily equal to 1x1000000. 
The MATLAB documentation only says that

> The function fun must accept two arrays of the same size and return an
>   array of corresponding values. It must perform element-wise
>   operations.

On my system, for example, its size was 14x14.

Comment: This is a great answer! However, I just had a side remark. Suppose we do not convert to Cartesian coordinates and instead plot for `theta` and `omega`; why does the `theta` axis then not stop at 2*pi?

Comment: @Jason Born Try using `axis tight;` after the `surface` function call

Comment: Yes, I was just confused by the fact that it extended to 6..*something*, but of course, this is just the numerical approximation for 2*pi.

Answer (score 2):

[`integral2(fun, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) calculates the volume under the plane described by the function `z = fun(x, y)` inside the given `x` and `y` limits.

So, for one value of `(x, y)`, `fun` should return only one `z` value, which is not the case in your example. You should really check the meaning of your function and determine which integral you want to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `numel` on `xx`, since it's a function parameter that is passed by the integration function. 
You actually do not know its size and cannot multiply it with a constant size matrix.